# WPF: how to access a hosted usr control's element?

Tags: wpf

I Create a user control in "MyControl.xaml" like this:

```
 <TreeView x:name="treeView" Grid.Row="0"/>

 <!-- Rest of doc -->
```

and the user control get hosted in MainWindow.xaml:
  ...
  
  ...

Now how can I access the object treeView in the xaml behind code in MainWindow.xaml.cs?
I Tried this but failed.
  MyControl.treeView.Items.Add(item); // object item created somewhere.

I Got the Error:
 Error  1   An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or  property 'MyNameSpace.MyControl.treeView

What am I supposed to do about this?

Comment: I am sorry. My Network is not serve the editing well. The post looks messy. I got nice answer from Milan anyway.

Comment: I also recommand a wonderful artical "WPF: A Beginner's Guide: Part 2" written by Sacha Barber (CodeProject). It help me either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have created a Usercontrol with name "UC" as below

```
   <Grid>
        <StackPanel>
            <TextBlock>Child</TextBlock>
            <TreeView x:Name="treeView"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
```

Added the control to its host

```
    <Grid>
       <local:UC x:Name="MyUC" />
    </Grid>
```

And in code behind I can access it like...

```
MyUC.treeView.Items.Add("Item");
```

Please check your implementation